# Selecting FPGA to implement PCIe

Tags: fpga, pcie

Hy i would like to play around with PCIe.

My Goals are:

- Implement a read and write able BAR.
- Implement a DMA that copies data from my Device to the PCs Memory.

I am beginer Level at FPGAs I have a working embeded system with some Sample Code that "runs" on a Virtex 5 XC5VLX20T. (Just smashed to gether some Example Code till it seemed to work.)
I wondered if it is possible to implement this on a ZYNQ XC7Z010-1CLG400C to.

**So my main Question is what do i need to look for when selecting an FPGA using it for PCIe?**

Comment: I would look for FPGA dev board with PCIe interface...

Comment: The Zynq 7010 doesn't have a PCIe interface. You need the 7015 or 7030. Eval boards for those are a little harder to come by. Zynq adds an additional layer of complexity that you may not want to take on - an Artix board may be easier to work with.

Comment: Ok whats that extra complexity? (never worked with Zynq before) i just saw they have an integrated ARM and the demo board had HDMI on it that looked promising to use in future experimenting.

Comment: The extra complexity is that ARM. The Zynq is an Artix plus an ARM. The PCIe component is in the Artix side. So either way you'll have to implement the complete PCIe solution in the Artix. But depending on what you want to do with this PCIe connection, the Zynq may be a valuable addition - you could take that PCIe data and route it to some other peripheral. It's just all work above and beyond the PCIe link itself.

Comment: The PCIe in a Zync/Artix doesn't seem to fit with the OP's desire, at least as I read it. They want to actually implement the PCIe interface themselves, including things like the BAR. With a Zynq/Artix, you get PCIe pre-built, so you just use the existing hardware.

Comment: There are various FPGAs which have PCIe in them ready to go. But that module is ready-to-go to some level (varies depending on device, who made it and how much you are paying). If all you're after is an FPGA you can do PCIe with, and you're willing to take up all the time and space with writing the PCIe code, you only need an FPGA which has suitable differential signalling pins

Comment: Few souls would be brave/foolish enough to attempt to implement a PCIe interface starting with nothing but the transceiver pins, certainly not an “FPGA beginner”. The Xilinx PCIe core is hardly plug-n-play – it presents a Transaction Layer interface that still requires a significant effort to make it do anything. It will be a challenging project – good luck!

Comment: Ok i now got a ARTY A7 board with an XC7A35T according to this: https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/pcie_7x/v3_3/pg054-7series-pcie.pdf it should be capable  of pcie. I now downloaded Vivado 2020.1 . After refreshing my VHDL knowledge i wanted to try my luck with the PCIe IpCore but i can't find it. Do i need a special license?

Comment: Ok not every XC7A35T has the PCIe integrated -.- . I have a ARTIX 7A35T CSG324 and unfortunatly that has no support.